# Introducing Linguistics.SE University Ambassadors Program: calling students and teachers

Tags: discussion

StackExchange is looking for students and teachers who might be interested in helping us kick off/formalize a university pizza ambassador-type program. Linguistics.StackExchange would like to sponsor university students (college or graduate) and faculty members who are excited about Linguistics, Stack Exchange and free food. Contact Seth Rogers for more details about the program and to get involved.

Comment: has the University Ambassador Program been successful? Over at CogSci.SE [we are looking for ways to promote ourselves](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/444/29).

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry I don't have enough rep to make comments yet)

Hi Seth, this is something I am definitely interested in. I'm 4th year undergrad at McGill University. What's the best way to contact you?

Comment: Posting, emailing or dropping a note in chat. Just sent you an email. Thanks!